# Bootstrap well issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a one-row form in a **well** followed by a **div**. Somehow the **well** is messing up the **div**. It looses the background and border among other things. Is this a bug or something I missed?

Without the well:
[image]

With the well:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="well well-sm col-xs-12" style='background-color:yellow; border-radius:15px;'>
<form>
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style='text-align:center'>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>



<div  style='width:768px; height:35px; margin:0px;background-color:green; border:3px solid orange;'>
Next Section.
</div>
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grmqNq?editors=1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

col-xs-12 on the well applies 'float' to the first div, your second div is appearing behind the first div. either remove that class or apply a col-xs-12 on the next section as well

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Also, <div  class='clearfix'></div> seems to do the trick.